# how to set php variable to html input tag in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need how to set variable value to html input tag,i have a variable value i need to pass html tag please help.

my mysql code:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
include('db_connection.php');
 if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
        $skills = $_POST["skills"];
        //print_r($skills);die;
    }
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `tbl_master_property` WHERE `name` ='$skills'";
  $result=$conn->query($sql);
   while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) { 
    $project[] = $row;
}
foreach ($project as $value) {
  $pg_address = $value['pg_address'];
  $pg_owner = $value['pg_incharge_name'];
} 
?>
```

Html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input class="border col-lg-12" type="text" name= "address" value ="<?php echo $value['pg_address']; ?>" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
            <label>PG Owner Name</label>
            <input class="border" type="text" name= "pg_owner_name" value ="<?php echo $value['pg_owner']; ?>"  required />
          </div>
```

Comment: Is this code in the same file?

Comment: You are really doing it wrong.

Comment: What is your problem / question?

Comment: same file only in this

Comment: `<?php echo $pg_address ?>` and `<?php echo $pg_owner ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
It will echo out Address and Project owner name in inputboxes, for each row in your table,

```
 <?php
//error_reporting(0);
include('db_connection.php');
 if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
        $skills = $_POST["skills"];
        //print_r($skills);die;
    }
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `tbl_master_property` WHERE `name` ='$skills'";
  $result=$conn->query($sql);
   while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) { 
    $project[] = $row;
}
foreach ($project as $value) {
  $pg_address = $value['pg_address'];
  $pg_owner = $value['pg_incharge_name'];
  echo '<div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input class="border col-lg-12" type="text" name= "address" value ="'.$pg_address.'" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
            <label>PG Owner Name</label>
            <input class="border" type="text" name= "pg_owner_name" value ="'.$pg_owner.'"  required />
        </div>';
} 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $skills = $_POST["skills"];
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM `tbl_master_property` WHERE `name` ='$skills'";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $value= $row[0];
}
?>


<input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $value['pg_address'];?>">
<input type="text" name="pg_owner_name" value="<?php echo $value['pg_owner'];?>">
```